# can l3keys process multiple 'submodule'?

Tags: expl3, l3keys, pgfopts

I would like to know if I can use `l3keys` to process multiple submodules as pgfoption can do ?

Here is a MWE to illustrate my question:

- a package file `mypkg.sty` (containing in comment the error I get when I try to compile the LaTeX file):

```
\ProvidesExplPackage{mypkg}{2024/01/01}{v0.0.0}{mypkg test}

\keys_define:nn { mypkg / title }
{
    title .choice:,
    title .usage:n = { general },
    title .default:n = { regular },
    title / regular .code:n = 
    {
        \PackageWarning {mypkg} {We~use~regular~title!}
    },
    title / smallcaps .code:n = 
    {
        \PackageWarning {mypkg} {We~use~smallcaps~title!}
    },
    title / unknown .code:n = { \PackageWarning {mypkg} {unknown~title~option!} },
}

\keys_define:nn { mypkg / font }
{
    font .choice:,
    font .usage:n = { general },
    font .default:n = { regular },
    font / regular .code:n = 
    {
        \PackageWarning {mypkg} {We~use~regular~font!}
    },
    font / bold .code:n = 
    {
        \PackageWarning {mypkg} {We~use~bold~font!}
    },
    font / unknown .code:n = { \PackageWarning {mypkg} {unknown~font~option!} },
}

% \ProcessKeyOptions % -> ! LaTeX Error: Unknown option 'title' for package mypkg.
\ProcessKeyOptions[mypkg/title, mypkg/font] % -> ! LaTeX Error: Unknown option 'title' for package mypkg.
% \ProcessKeyOptions[mypkg/title] % -> ! LaTeX Error: Unknown option 'font' for package mypkg.
% \ProcessKeyOptions[mypkg/font] % -> ! LaTeX Error: Unknown option 'title' for package mypkg.
```

- a LaTeX file, `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[title=smallcaps, font=regular]{mypkg}

\begin{document}
TEST
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your separation of choice keys into submodules looks odd, imho. I guess this is caused by stripping down your real example for this MWE, but otherwise, just drop the submodules.

Comment: @Skillmon Yes it is cause by stripping down my real usage example. Otherwise, I agree that removing the submodules and keeping everything in the same module is a better option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following uses an unknown handler of yet another submodule to load the keys of your submodules. This breaks global keys (so the options given to the `\documentclass`) but otherwise works reasonable well.

```
\ProvidesExplPackage{mypkg}{2024/01/01}{v0.0.0}{mypkg test}

\seq_const_from_clist:Nn \c__mypkg_load_submodules_seq { title, font }
\keys_define:nn { mypkg / load }
  {
    unknown .code:n =
      \__mypkg_keymodules:Vn \l_keys_key_str {#1}
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mypkg_keymodules:nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \c__mypkg_load_submodules_seq
      {
        \keys_if_exist:nnT { mypkg / ##1 } {#1}
          {
            % missing feature in l3keys, we have no better way to detect an
            % omitted value, so we have to guess that all empty values are in
            % fact omitted values.
            \tl_if_empty:nTF {#2}
              { \keys_set:nn { mypkg / ##1 } { #1 } }
              { \keys_set:nn { mypkg / ##1 } { #1 = {#2} } }
            \prg_break:
          }
      }
    \msg_error:nnn { mypkg } { unknown-key } {#1}
    \prg_break_point:
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__mypkg_keymodules:nn { Vn }
\msg_new:nnn { mypkg } { unknown-key } { Unknown~ key~ #1~ encountered. }

\keys_define:nn { mypkg / title }
{
    title .choice:,
    title .usage:n = { general },
    title .default:n = { regular },
    title / regular .code:n = 
    {
        \PackageWarning {mypkg} {We~use~regular~title!}
    },
    title / smallcaps .code:n = 
    {
        \PackageWarning {mypkg} {We~use~smallcaps~title!}
    },
    title / unknown .code:n = { \PackageWarning {mypkg} {unknown~title~option!} },
}

\keys_define:nn { mypkg / font }
{
    font .choice:,
    font .usage:n = { general },
    font .default:n = { regular },
    font / regular .code:n = 
    {
        \PackageWarning {mypkg} {We~use~regular~font!}
    },
    font / bold .code:n = 
    {
        \PackageWarning {mypkg} {We~use~bold~font!}
    },
    font / unknown .code:n = { \PackageWarning {mypkg} {unknown~font~option!} },
}

\ProcessKeyOptions[mypkg/load] % -> ! LaTeX Error: Unknown option 'title' for package mypkg.
```

---

## PoC

This is a PoC to parse the initial options via the submodules (so that global options work), but any future options via our `load`-submodule acting with an unknown-key handler, all that while parsing every option just once.

This is a bit convoluted admittedly.

```
\ProvidesExplPackage{mypkg}{2024/01/01}{v0.0.0}{mypkg test}

\seq_const_from_clist:Nn \c__mypkg_load_submodules_seq { title, font }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mypkg_keymodules:nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \c__mypkg_load_submodules_seq
      {
        \keys_if_exist:nnT { mypkg / ##1 } {#1}
          {
            % missing feature in l3keys, we have no better way to detect an
            % omitted value, so we have to guess that all empty values are in
            % fact omitted values.
            \tl_if_empty:nTF {#2}
              { \keys_set:nn { mypkg / ##1 } { #1 } }
              { \keys_set:nn { mypkg / ##1 } { #1 = {#2} } }
            \prg_break:
          }
      }
    \msg_error:nnn { mypkg } { unknown-key } {#1}
    \prg_break_point:
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__mypkg_keymodules:nn { Vn }
\msg_new:nnn { mypkg } { unknown-key } { Unknown~ key~ #1~ encountered. }

\keys_define:nn { mypkg / title }
{
    title .choice:,
    title .usage:n = { general },
    title .default:n = { regular },
    title / regular .code:n = 
    {
        \PackageWarning {mypkg} {We~use~regular~title!}
    },
    title / smallcaps .code:n = 
    {
        \PackageWarning {mypkg} {We~use~smallcaps~title!}
    },
    title / unknown .code:n = { \PackageWarning {mypkg} {unknown~title~option!} },
    unknown .code:n = {}
}

\keys_define:nn { mypkg / font }
{
    font .choice:,
    font .usage:n = { general },
    font .default:n = { regular },
    font / regular .code:n = 
    {
        \PackageWarning {mypkg} {We~use~regular~font!}
    },
    font / bold .code:n = 
    {
        \PackageWarning {mypkg} {We~use~bold~font!}
    },
    font / unknown .code:n = { \PackageWarning {mypkg} {unknown~font~option!} },
    unknown .code:n = {}
}

\ProcessKeyOptions[mypkg/title]
\ProcessKeyOptions[mypkg/font]

\keys_define:nn { mypkg / load }
  {
    unknown .code:n = {}
  }
\ProcessKeyOptions[mypkg/load] % -> ! LaTeX Error: Unknown option 'title' for package mypkg.

\keys_define:nn { mypkg / load }
  {
     unknown .code:n =
      \__mypkg_keymodules:Vn \l_keys_key_str {#1}
  }
\clist_map_inline:nn { title, font }
  {
    \keys_define:nn { mypkg / #1 }
      {
        \unknown .code:n =
          \msg_error:nne { mypkg } { unknown-key } \l_keys_key_str
      }
  }
```

Comment: Can you develop a bit more about the consequences of this global keys breaking ? Because it seems interesting.

Comment: @R.N that goes into the implementation details of `\ProcessKeyOptions`, basically for the global options it does a `\keys_if_exist:nTF` as well to filter which options of the global list to forward to the package, which this here breaks, as none of the options are defined in `mypkg/load`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you'd want to define keys this way. But you can simply add management of unknown keys in each module.

```
\ProvidesExplPackage{mypkg}{2024/01/01}{v0.0.0}{mypkg test}

\keys_define:nn { mypkg/title }
{
    title .choice:,
    title .usage:n = { general },
    title .default:n = { regular },
    title / regular .code:n = 
    {
        \PackageWarning {mypkg} {We~use~regular~title!}
    },
    title / smallcaps .code:n = 
    {
        \PackageWarning {mypkg} {We~use~smallcaps~title!}
    },
    title / unknown .code:n = { \PackageWarning {mypkg} {unknown~title~option!} },
    unknown .code:n = {},
}
\keys_define:nn { mypkg/font }
{
    font .choice:,
    font .usage:n = { general },
    font .default:n = { regular },
    font / regular .code:n = 
    {
        \PackageWarning {mypkg} {We~use~regular~font!}
    },
    font / bold .code:n = 
    {
        \PackageWarning {mypkg} {We~use~bold~font!}
    },
    font / unknown .code:n = { \PackageWarning {mypkg} {unknown~font~option!} },
    unknown .code:n = {},
}

\ProcessKeyOptions[mypkg/title]
\ProcessKeyOptions[mypkg/font]
```

Comment: if you do that like this you can't use the title key in a second package loading, it is then ignored: `\usepackage[title=smallcaps]{mypkg}\usepackage[title=regular]{mypkg}`. Imho it is better to put keys meant as package options under one label.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I agree. But why should one want to load twice a package?

Comment: well it happens. We just adapted xcolor to use the new keyval to avoid option clash errors if it is loaded more than once.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I agree it happens to load twice a package. Do you have a workaround to suggest ?

Comment: @R.N my solution works for loading a package twice (though it doesn't work well for the global list). A hybrid solution of this and mine would do.

Comment: @R.N as I wrote, I would use only one label and not split the keys into submodules. For package options that is imho overdoing.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, of course only one label is more efficient but not applicable in my real case.

Comment: @Skillmon For the record, a dummy hybrid solution leads to keys treated 1 extras time during the first package loading.

Comment: @R.N I doubt that. If you really have so many options that a subdividing is needed, don't do it with package options, write a setup command instead.

Comment: @R.N no, this is possible without parsing keys multiple times, though it's a bit convoluted. See the edit in my answer.